# How to rename all md type files under subfolders recursive?

Tags: bash, find, rename, xargs, mv

```
$ tree .

.
├── tmp1
│   └── acsfd.md
├── tmp2
│   └── adb.md
└── tmp3
    └── aa23aa.md
...
└── tmpn
    └── random.md
```

Want to rename all `md` files to `index.md`,

I tried:

```
find . -name "*.md" -exec mv {} index.md \;
```

But this will delete all `md` files and create one `index.md` on current folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you need `-execdir` instead of `-exec` to run `mv` in the directory containing the matched file:

```
$ tree
.
├── tmp1
│   └── rand32726.md
├── tmp2
│   └── rand16097.md
├── tmp3
│   └── rand10683.md
└── tmpn
    └── rand23531.md

4 directories, 4 files
$ find . -iname '*.md' -execdir mv {} index.md \;
$ tree
.
├── tmp1
│   └── index.md
├── tmp2
│   └── index.md
├── tmp3
│   └── index.md
└── tmpn
    └── index.md

4 directories, 4 files
```